# A verb macro that branches based on its argument (implementing an association list)

Tags: xetex, pdftex, etoolbox, xparse

I'm looking to implement a simple association list in LaTeX.  The idea is that I can type `\branch|Some arbitrary !_{} text here|`, and `Some arbitrary !_{} text here` will be looked up in a (static) table of `string → string` mappings and replaced as appropriate.

There are two tricky aspects:

- Parsing the verbatim argument of the command.  For this, I can use `xparse` and its `\NewDocumentCommand`.
- Implementing the association list.  For this I can use nested `\ifstrequal` commands.

I'm not sure how to combine the two, however.  Here is an MWE; it works for the association list `AAA → "Found some As", BBB → "Found some Bs"`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\branch{v}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{AAA}{Found some As!}{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{BBB}{Found some Bs!}{%
      Key not found: \texttt{#1}!}}}

\begin{document}
\branch|AA|\\
\branch|AAA|\\
\branch/BBB/\\
\branch!BB!

\branch|AA!}/|
\branch|BB!\/:|
\end{document}
```

**How should I modify this MWE it to add mappings for the last two keys (`AA!}/` and `BB!\/:`)?** Although my `\branch` command parses them fine, I don't know of an elegant way to pass a verbatim string to `\ifstrequal`. The best way I have at the moment is the following:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\MakeTable{v v v v}{%
  \NewDocumentCommand\fancybranch{v}{%
    \ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{Found some As!}{%
      \ifstrequal{##1}{#2}{Found some Bs!}{%
        \ifstrequal{##1}{#3}{Found some weird As!}{%
          \ifstrequal{##1}{#4}{Found some weird Bs!}{%
            Key not found: \texttt{#1}!}}}}}}

\MakeTable|AAA||BBB||AA!}/||BB!\/:|
```

This lets me use `\fancybranch` instead of `branch`, and everything seems ok, but it doesn't look very elegant; advice would be very welcome. **Is there a better way to implement this**?  Using `etoolbox` and `xparse` and relying on this `\MakeTable` macro looks a bit heavyweight (on the other hand, the code is pretty readable as it is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you commented that a lighterweight version might be possible, a package free version, note that this uses the csname hash table to look up the items rather than a linear search through a list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\branch{%
\begingroup
\let\do\@makeother\dospecials
\xxbranch}
\def\xxbranch#1{\def\tmp##1#1{\endgroup\xbranch{##1}}\tmp}

\def\xbranch#1{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname X-\detokenize{#1}\endcsname\relax
\texttt{\detokenize{#1}} Not found%
\else
\csname X-\detokenize{#1}\expandafter\endcsname
\fi}

\def\defbranch{%
\begingroup
\let\do\@makeother\dospecials
\xxdefbranch}
\def\xxdefbranch#1{\def\tmp##1#1{\endgroup\xdefbranch{##1}}\tmp}
\def\xdefbranch#1{\expandafter\def\csname X-\detokenize{#1}\endcsname}

\defbranch|AAA|{Found some As!}
\defbranch|BBB|{Found some Bs!}
\defbranch|AA!}/|{Found some weird As!}
\defbranch|BB!\/:|{Found some weird Bs!}


\begin{document}
\branch|AA|\\
\branch|AAA|\\
\branch/BBB/\\
\branch!BB!

\branch|AA!}/|
\branch|BB!\/:|
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ooh neat! Now I just need to learn about `@makeother`, `detokenize`, `do`, and `dospecials` :)  One small question: can you maybe explain how the \begingroup and \endgroup are paired up?

Comment: @Clément the outer macro starts a group switches the catcodes of everything then the inner macro grabs makes a temporary macro delimited by whatever is needed (eg `\def\tmp#1|` if need to grab up to `|`) and then that `\tmp` macro starts its replacement text with `\endgroup` to restore all the catcodes.  If it were not for unpaired `{]` you could skip all the catcode weirdness and nested catcodes and just have a single definition of `\branch` and `\defbranch` using `\detokenize`  but you can not scan mis-matched braces that way.

Answer (score 4):

Use the full force of `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\branch{v}
 {
  \clement_branch:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \clement_branch:n
 {
  \str_case_x:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {AAA}{Found~some~As!}
    {BBB}{Found~some~Bs!}
    {AA!\c_right_brace_str/}{Found~some~weird~As!}
    {BB!\c_backslash_str/:}{Found~some~weird~Bs!}
   }
   {Key~not~found~\texttt{#1}!}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
1. \branch|AA|

2. \branch|AAA|

3. \branch/BBB/

4. \branch!BB!

5. \branch|AA!}/|

6. \branch|BB!\/:|

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative approach that makes it easier to define the various branches.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\branch{v}
 {
  \clement_branch:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\definebranch}{vm}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_clement_branches_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \clement_branch:n
 {
  \prop_get:NnN \g_clement_branches_prop { #1 } \l__clement_branch_temp_tl
  \quark_if_no_value:VTF \l__clement_branch_temp_tl
   { Key~not~found~\texttt{#1}! }
   { \tl_use:N \l__clement_branch_temp_tl }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \quark_if_no_value:nTF { V }
\prop_new:N \g_clement_branches_prop
\tl_new:N \l__clement_branch_temp_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definebranch|AAA|{Found some As!}
\definebranch|BBB|{Found some Bs!}
\definebranch|AA!}/|{Found some weird As!}
\definebranch|BB!\/:|{Found some weird Bs!}

\begin{document}
1. \branch|AA|

2. \branch|AAA|

3. \branch/BBB/

4. \branch!BB!

5. \branch|AA!}/|

6. \branch|BB!\/:|

\end{document}
```

Comment: Neat, thanks! Are you missing the definition of `\c_right_brace_str/` though?

Comment: @Clément No, `\c_right_brace_str` is predefined; perhaps you have to update your TeX distribution. I added an alternative approach.

Comment: Great, thanks! It's very nice to be able to easily define new branches easily.